# Send a Text File from a Raspberry Pi to an Android app

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, send, logfile

This is a rather general question, I hope it fits to Stackoverflow.
I want to develop an Android app which should have the possibility to recieve a Text File send from an Raspberry Pi. I want to do this because I'm building my own Alarm System for my front door. My raspberry write log files whenever my Door is opened and Closed. This works perfectly fine. And now I want this Logfiles to be send to my App. I had the Idea to display the logfiles on my own ftp-server and just make a Webview on the App, but I don't think this is a good solution because I want to get a notification whenever a Logfile is send (or and new logfile is displayed on the webview) and I don't know if it is possible to get a notification when a web view changes. So I have two Questions: 
1. Can you get a notification when a web view changes?
 2.Is there a better aproach (just send a text file and get notification when a file arrives)? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you downvote the Question please explain why, so I can edit the Question or move it to another location. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour part "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" ...your question is too broad

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to send a Textfile from a Raspberry to an Android app. If so what's a good aproach to tackle that Problem. I don't know how I should be more specific or do you mean that general topic is an off topic question?

Comment: yes, it is possible... is it good? term "good"  is realative ... you should: do some research, try some solutions

Comment: Why do not you just send an email from raspberry? You would have to handle communication all yourself in the other case.

Comment: I also thought about an Email notification. What I have in mind for the Future is to set the Alarm on and off via my app and it would just be nice if the same app gets the notifications.

Comment: I think I will make a new Gmail account and filter the emails from the Raspberry to get only notifications from the raspberry

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is the raspberry pi is the "trigger", not Android. So you have to get the raspberry pi to initiate the transfer, then your Android can retrieve this log file when it needs to. You could poll your pi, but this is generally a waste of resources.

What you'll probably want to do is send a "push" message from the raspberry pi to Google. Google will then send a notification to your android app. You then code your Android app to respond to this however you choose.

In your case, upon receiving this push, your app would obviously then goto the raspberry Pi and retrieve the latest log file (web services, ftp, etc) and display it.

Now there's too much here for us to describe in much more detail, you'll have to take a few tutorials and piece it together, here are a few example tutorials that may help you get started:

**Google Cloud Messaging** (Responsible for transferring push message from your pi to android).
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will definetly try this aproach and study those tutorials!